# Any free Text To Speech for browsers?

Tags: text-to-speech

Wondering if there is any Text to Speech software available as a plug in for IE or Firefox.

Comment: For those that might be marking this down as a non-programming related question, keep in mind that web developers would need a TTS browser to accurately test the accessibility of the websites they build.

Comment: There are some text-to-speech JavaScript libraries, which don't require any plugins. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279291/a-good-text-to-speech-javascript-library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[WebAnywhere](http://webanywhere.cs.washington.edu/) is a university project aimed at creating a site that allows you to use text to speech from any browser at any location, without installing anything or using any plugins.

You can [try it out](http://webanywhere.cs.washington.edu/wa.php) and see for yourself. I was pretty impressed with it when I first heard of it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [NVDA](http://www.nvda-project.org/) (NonVisual Desktop Access) which is an open source general purpose screen reader for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It is built in for Safari on Mac OSX.  Highlight any text and go to the menu, Safari > Services > Speech > Start Speaking Text.

Answer (score 1):

- [Fire Vox](http://www.firevox.clcworld.net/)
- [Fangs](http://www.standards-schmandards.com/projects/fangs/)

Comment: Fire Vox - clever clever name

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for plugins for IE and Firefox but I thought I'd just add that Opera supports text to speech (both for issuing commands and for Opera to read web / email to you) out of the box (in Windows and possibly Mac OS).

See the [Opera Voice](http://www.opera.com/products/desktop/voice/) page.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Narrator is part of a default XP installation, and can be used in any browser.  I also suggest you try out [Thunder](http://www.screenreader.net/), which is free and can work with IE and most other Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox, there is LowBrowse, which has text to speech for the
paragraph that the cursor is in.