# Text-To-Speech with jquery API HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, text-to-speech

Is it possible to build a website that has the capability of reading a textbox text on a user longClick and that works on different kinds of browsers?

The website should also work in mobile devices..

Thanks!

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144117/any-free-text-to-speech-for-browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try jTalk:

http://www.jtalkplugin.com/

It creates mp3 files to play in client. So no problem should be found in even mobile devices.

Also there is a thread which described other ways to fix this problem:

[Any free Text To Speech for browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144117/any-free-text-to-speech-for-browsers)

Comment: Both the links are non-existent now.