# Web Accessibility: Screen Reader Embedding

Tags: web, accessibility, screen-readers

I don't know if my question make sense. But my client want to know if it is possible to embed a screen reader? i.e. when a website user click a button on website, the reader will read out the text or para, his mouse is on.

I am not sure where and what to look, searching google give various plugin and software to install on computer, or browser. Still searching but thought to ask if anyone knows and can help me faster thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You are looking for [text-to-speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) (tag on SO: [text-to-speech](/questions/tagged/text-to-speech)).

For jQuery, see for example this question: [Text-To-Speech with jquery API HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5680058/1591669)

But note this is in general not a good idea. Users that *need* a screen reader already use one (besides that, your alternative wouldn’t be a full substitute for a screen reader, of course). Users that don’t need a screen reader will likely ignore this possibility (well, most of these sound awful).

*If* you implement it, you should make sure that it doesn’t start automatically (i.e., not after page load, not after hover, etc.), but only after firing an explicit action (e.g., a button). And provide a way to immediately stop it (e.g., a pause button).

Comment: So, most of stuff I still found looks like are for desktop application or Browser Extension. And yes I agree that most people already have screen reader, and a website developer we just have to make it readable through those software. And we don't actually have to embed Reader with us. Hope I am correct in my wording. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: +1 If a user needs a screen reader (I mean, if he MUST use a screen reader because he's totally blind for example), how will he click on a button? How did he launch this software called a web browser on his desktop and went to an URL and then tabbed the exact number of times needed to reach this button without any feedback since he switched on his computer? And how does he use other software like text editor, mail, mp3 reader, etc or visit other sites? With his already installed screen reader (NVDA, VoiceOver, ORCA, JAWS, etc). It may still have some use, but not that much.