# How do I implement text-to-speech in html or javascript for web browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accessibility, text-to-speech

I want a webpage to read some text out loud (in a robot voice!).

On this webpage, there's a button that, when clicked, randomly displays one of 3 sentences.  I'd like to have another button that can be clicked that will read the text aloud.  Alternatively, the text can be read aloud automatically when the first button is clicked.

here's the relevant code...

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var randomStrings = [
     "this is an example of a random string",
     "here's another random string",
     "or maybe this string will be chosen at random"
      ];
    function RndMsg() {
      var msg = randomStrings[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomStrings.length)];
      document.getElementById('randomDiv').innerHTML = msg;
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="button" value="Randomize!" name="sessionid" onclick="RndMsg()"/>
//click the button->text appears below... i want browser or OS to read it aloud
  </form>
  <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
    <div id="randomDiv"> </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a newbie, so I'm wondering if there's a simple way to do this.  thanks!

Comment: http://vozme.com/webmasters.php?lang=en

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144117/any-free-text-to-speech-for-browsers

Comment: I saw the older stackoverflow post, but was wondering about a solution that would work w/ any browser.  I will check out vozMe, though, thanks!

Comment: http://responsivevoice.org/ is very good see this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used [speak.js](https://github.com/kripken/speak.js) for some personal projects before.

From the GitHub page:

> A port of the eSpeak speech synthesizer from C++ to JavaScript using
>   Emscripten.
>
> Enables text-to-speech on the web using only JavaScript and HTML5.
>
> Online demo: http://syntensity.com/static/espeak.html

Comment: this worked perfectly.  I would upvote your answer but my reputation is too low.  thanks.